# Getting an element by id and then storing it in a variable to then be appended to an li?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

new to JS here and trying to create a basic to-do list. I've gone through CodeAcademy and TreeHouse tutorials and understand functions, if statements, loops, objects etc but what I find is until you attempt to create your own project you realise none of it has actually sunk in!

So I'm currently trying to build up a basic to-do list that will eventually let me add new tasks, mark tasks as finished etc. I know there's tutorials on the web, but without creating it myself I don't think I'll learn.

So, I'm getting the value typed into the element named "taskField" and storing it in a variable called task:

```
var task = document.getElementById("taskField");
```

Then, I am creating a function called addTask():

```
function addTask() {
 var liNode = document.createElement("li");  // Creates an li tag and sets it as a variable known as liNode
 liNode.appendChild(task); // Appends liNode to the value of the variable task declared above
 document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(liNode); //  Gets the ul and adds the li item
}
```

The function is called when the button is clicked, here's my jsfiddle so you can see all my HTML markup as well: https://jsfiddle.net/3b5rprx0/

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Cheers.

Comment: instead of appending the entire input element to linode , only set the value property to task.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you have done is,

1) You were trying to add the entire textbox into the 'li' element.
Instead you need to get its value using 'value' property.

It shoud be like,

```
var task = document.getElementById("taskField").value;
var liNode = document.createElement("li");
liNode.innerHTML=task;
```

I have changed the code. Have a look at it.
https://jsfiddle.net/gox8x6ot/

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't actually setting the value as the variable, I was setting the entire textbox. Haha, cheers dude! Can I ask the reasoning behind innerHTML instead of appendChild as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code a little bit like this

```
function addTask() {
  // create li element
  var liNode = document.createElement("li");

  // get value of id 'taskField'
  var task = document.getElementById("taskField").value;

  // set content of li above
  liNode.innerHTML = task;

  // append li element to taskList
  document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(liNode);
}
```

to manipulate html, it is easier to use jquery instead of using native

info: https://jquery.com/

you can find many tutorial and faq about jquery via google

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code. Updated code is given bellow.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<form id="taskForm">
  <input id="taskField" type="text" value=''>
</form>
<button id="btn" onclick="addTask()">Add Task!</button>
<ul id="taskList">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Update Your script with

```
<script>    
var task = document.getElementById("taskField");
var tasklist = document.getElementById("taskList");
function addTask() {
  var mytask = task.value;
      var textval = document.createTextNode(mytask);
  var liNode = document.createElement("li");
  liNode.appendChild(textval);
  document.getElementById("taskList").appendChild(liNode);
} 
</script>
```

See this code
[Updated Code Preview on Codepen](https://codepen.io/saurabh21shukla/pen/dXOZpv?editors=1011)